# Run-Time error '424' Object required on MatchData(item1.Row) = item2.Value

Tags: excel, vba

I perform a string comparison between 2 columns.

I compare the 1st column data with 2nd column data. If there is match, then I need to write the data from column 2 to column 1.

When I execute this code, I came across to

> Run-Time error '424' Object required

on the line `MatchData(item1.Row) = item2.Value`.

If I comment this line, then I don't get this error message.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim attr1 As Range, data1 As Range
Dim item1, item2, item3, lastRow, lastRow2
Dim UsrInput, UsrInput2 As Variant
Dim Cnt As Integer, LineCnt As Integer
Dim MatchData(1 To 9000) As String
Dim i As Integer            

For i = 1 To 9000
    MatchData(i) = ""
Next i

UsrInput = InputBox("Enter Atribute Column")
UsrInput2 = InputBox("Enter Column Alphabet to compare")

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lastRow
End With

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput2).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lastRow
End With

Set attr1 = Range(UsrInput & "2:" & UsrInput & lastRow)
Set data1 = Range(UsrInput2 & "2:" & UsrInput2 & lastRow)

For Each item1 In attr1
    item1.Value = Replace(item1.Value, " ", "")
Next item1

For Each item1 In attr1
    If item1 = "" Then Exit For

    item1 = "*" & item1 & "*"

    For Each item2 In data1                
        If item2 Like item1 Then
            MatchData(item1.Row) = item2.Value
            MatchData(item2.Row) = item2.Value
            Debug.Print "Match"
            'Debug.Print item2.Row
            Debug.Print item1.Row
            Debug.Print item1
            Debug.Print item2
            Debug.Print " "
        End If
    Next item2

Next item1

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change it to `Set MatchData(item1.Row) = item2.Value`?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `item1.Row` exists? When the error box appears, press `Debug` and use the Locals window to inspect `item1`.

Comment: As MatchData is Dim'd as String; you should cast item2.Value as a string, so this might help solve your issue: MatchData(item2.Row) = CStr(item2.Value)

Comment: Hi jsheeran, I have tried your suggestion and it still shows the same error message.

Comment: Hi Flephal , I have tried your suggestion and it still shows the same error message

Comment: HI AlexP, the item1 is a data from the range, attr1 in the code. So it should show the row number of the each data in the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to:

```
    For Each item1 In attr1
         If item1.value = "" Then Exit For

         item1.value = "*" & item1 & "*"
```

Comment: HI mkinson, the error message is related to line which this code " MatchData(item1.Row) = item2.value". I believe it is having problem on item1.row as not able to recognize.

Comment: Yes, but I believe that's because of the line "If item2 Like item1", but item1 has no value because you have it assigned as item1 = "" instead of item1.value = "" and item1 = "/*" instead of item1.value - "/*". I had run the code on my system and it seemed to work after making the changes I suggested above.

Comment: Hi mkinson, thank you so much for your help. Your solution helps to resolve this issue. Appreciate for your help on this matter.